# jQuery ajax form submission not displaying results

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm attempting to submit a single textarea form to the same page the form is on using ajax. I want to display the data submitted after it's been processed by the PHP at the top of the page, but I don't really understand ajax, so it's no surprise that I don't understand why this isn't working.

Here's the PHP at the top of the page:

```
if(isset($_POST['convert'])) {
  $string = htmlspecialchars(strtolower($_POST['convert']));
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($string);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Here's the html form:

```
<form id="text" name="text" action="" method="POST">
  <textarea name="convert" id="convert">This is data</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here's the jQuery that submits the form:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(html) {
      alert('ok');
    }
  });
});
```

When I submit the form, I get the alert message, but the PHP `$string` variable never gets echoed. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you know it's not being echoed, you don't do anything with the result of the ajax call ?

Comment: Like I said, I want to post the form to the same page, and if you submit with regular old HTML, then you leave the action attribute blank to submit to the same page. There's minimal PHP involved, so what's the use in creating a special file just to post the data to?

Comment: Instead of ` alert('ok');` do ` alert(html);`. The php script is running not going to print anything to the screen when you run it from Ajax. You need to actually print the returned data us JS.

Comment: I've tried changing `url: $(this).attr('action')` to `url: window.location.href` and it does the exact same thing as leaving the action attribute blank. I get the alert, but the data never displays.

Comment: @Amygdala how are you trying to display the data?

Comment: But where is the data supposed to display, it's not being put to use anywhere in the above code?

Comment: I guess when I said **I don't really understand ajax**, I wasn't clear enough. I keep getting "You're not doing anything with the data", but I don't have the slightest clue _how_ to do anything with the data. I assumed that when you submitted via ajax with method set to POST, the actual `$_POST` global in PHP would be set. This is apparently not the case, so would anyone care to elaborate on _how_ to do **something** with the data?

Comment: @Amygdala `$_POST` is set, but not for the PHP script that rendered the page that is issuing the request (can you see the time loop?). It's set for a PHP script that is rendering the AJAX response, which can then be read by javascript.

Comment: Thank you for actually giving me something I can learn from rather than pointing a finger at the problem and expecting me to figure out the solution without understanding the problem to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That because you are not doing anything **with** the data:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(html) {
      console.log(html); // logs your response to the js console
      //appends your response to the doc body (if you _really_ wanted to do that)
      $('body').append(html); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There's also `$().load`, that the OP probably wants to use.

Comment: `$("body")` should be `$(document.body)`

Comment: @JanDvorak Yea, I had that originally, but then I changed it to the jQuery version of body.

Comment: Although this appends the entire document, I was able to learn from this example how to get just the value I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Amygdala - Yes, if you're posting to the same page with ajax, you'll have to use some sort of condition that ends the output before the entire page is rendered when an ajax call is made.